# maintain normal map scale when using a shape key

Tags: texturing, uv, normal-map, shape-keys

I will try to explain as best as I can what I am trying to accomplish

**Simply put:**

If you have a repeated seamless normal map, is there a way to stop it stretching when using a shape key while allowing the base texture to stretch.

**More detailed:**

If you have a flat plane with a lava texture and you use a shape key to make a bubble, is there a way to keep the normal map the same area scale.

So no matter how big or small the bubble gets it still has the same constant rough texture.

I'm thinking it will be to do with texture coordinate and mapping but I can't seem to figure it out.

unfortunately I don't have a save file to share.

Sorry if this makes little sense I can't think of a better way to describe what I'm attempting

Comment: You can do that by using any texture coordinate that doesn't depend on your object's geometry. Like the Wordl socket.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this. I taught myself blender and still have a lot to learn.

Comment: You could use geometry nodes to interpolate between different meshes, each UV unwrapped. So then you would interpolate not just the geometry, but also the UV map. Though UV unwrapping the meshes in such a way the interpolation makes sense, might turn out very tricky - this will depend on the effect you're going for with the mesh morphing…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to map textures onto an object independently of its geometry is to use tri-plannar mapping.

You can achieve this by using the texture coordinates of another object (typically an empty that you leave at the center of the world), and project your texture from a box shape around your object, with some eventual blending around the projection box's edges to hide the seems.

Though this method is more appropriate for using tiled repeatable textures.

Here's how it looks in the shader editor:

[image: demo nodes]

And how it looks when editing the object:

[image: demo gif]

If you want to use UVs instead, there isn't really a way. You could try to make duplicates of your UVs to adapt them for shapes that stretch too much, and then use a mix color node to switch between the two UV maps when you turn your shapekey on. But this will never be a perfect solution either.

[image: demo gif 2]

Comment: I think this will work for what I need, thank you